# Texture Wrapping to UV map in viewport but not in Render

Tags: rendering, texturing, uv

In my viewport my material has wrapped perfectly to my UV map and in the UV editor you can see the image lines up perfectly with my UV map. However, when I render my mushroom model the stem doesn't wrap properly and renders as white except for a small patch down the bottom.

Any help on how to fix this would be really appreciated! I've tried resetting normals, re-unwrapping it, deleting and recreating the material, relinking the file and changing the colour settings from default to UV but nothing as worked so far.[image]
[image]

Comment: hello could you please pack the image and share your file? https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: Do you have multiple UV maps?  If you do, use UV map nodes in materials to specify which UV map you want to use for your texture lookup.